# How to receive the "raw bytes" sent on the serial port in Virtual Box?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, cmd.exe, serial-port

I have enabled a serial port in Virtual Box, and redirected the output to the file `D:\1.bin`:

[image]

I have sent some data using the following command in cmd in Windows XP inside Virtual Box:

```
echo Hello > COM1
```

Also I have sent the same data to the serial port in Ubuntu 9.04 inside Virtual Box:

```
echo Hello > /dev/ttyS0
```

But the result saved in `D:\1.bin` was only the string "Hello" without the extra data like parity and stop bit.

Is there a way to be able to receive the "raw bytes" sent on the serial port?

Answer (score 0):

Parity and stop bits will not be included in this file.

The "*raw data*" refers to the payload... parity and stop bits are related to the framing and verification of the "*raw data*" on the physical medium.

---

It's also worth mentioning that UARTs can typically operate in 7-bit (text-only) and 8-bit (binary) modes.

The typical `8N1` that you see referrs to:

- 1 implicit start bit
- 8-bit data
- No parity
- 1 stop bit

This would come to 10-bits per 8-bits of data, which wouldn't work well in a file that stores 8-bits per byte anyway - add parity or another stop bit and you exacerbate the situation further.

Additionally, once you become interested in the framing, you *should really* also be interested in timing information such as baud rate and frame-spacing - something that your commands don't even configure.